# How to join two tables using LINQ xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

i am using xamarin forms with ORM EF i want to show data from product and salesOrderItems in data gridView. my problem that the grid is empty.here my code.

```
public SalesOrderDetailsVM(int salesOrderItemId)
    {
        _salesOrderItemId = salesOrderItemId;
        _context = new DatabaseContext();
        var salesOrderItem = _context.SalesOrderItems.Find(salesOrderItemId);
        var idsalesOrder = salesOrderItem.SalesOrderId;
        var salesOrder = _context.SalesOrders.Find(idsalesOrder);
        var idProd = salesOrderItem.ProductId;
        _context = new DatabaseContext();
        var Customer = _context.Customers.Where(t => t.CustomerId == salesOrder.CustomerId).FirstOrDefault();
        // Setting property values from customer and salesOrder object
        // that we get from database
        DateCreation = salesOrder.DateCreation;
        NumBc = salesOrder.NumBc;
        CustomerName = Customer.MangerFullName;
        CustomerCIN = Customer.CIN;
        var Products = (from p in _context.Products
                         join o in _context.SalesOrderItems
                         on p.ProductId equals o.ProductId

                         select new 
                         {
                             Code = p.Code,
                             Designation = p.Designation,
                             Order_Qty = o.Order_Qty,
                             PrixUnitaire = p.PrixUnitaire,
                             TotalHt = o.TotalHt

                         }).ToList();   }
```

Comment: We're going to need a bit more code. For starters the definition of the grid would help. Also there needs to be a property on your `ViewModel` somewhere that holds the list of items. Normally your `ViewModel` needs to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and then the setter of the list property should signal changes. That way the bindings can react to new values.

Comment: You might wanna create a bindable model that gets only the useful values from both your classes and then uses it, or else you can simply bind using the name of the class and property.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Knoop the grid definition
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" 
                          SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                          SelectionMode="None"  
                        >
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate BackgroundColor="DarkSlateGray"  >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Frame Padding="5" BorderColor="DarkSlateGray">
                                    <Grid Padding="5" >
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions BorderColor="DarkSlateGray">
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid BackgroundColor="Transparent" >
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions BorderColor="DarkSlateGray">
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding   Product.Code}"  VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="0" />
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Product.Designation}" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="1" />
                                        <Label  Text="{Binding  SalesOrderItem.Order_Qty}" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="2" />
                                        <Label Text="{Binding  Product.PrixUnitaire}" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="3" />
                                        <Label Text="{Binding SalesOrderItem.TotalHt}" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="4" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </Frame>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```